# Integrating Live Photos in my app

Tags: ios, swift, phlivephoto

I have some live photos that I am trying to use in my app. I am kind of confused on how to integrate them so I can use it in the app. I currently have an image view, but how do I add the live photo to it?

Comment: What do you mean "live photo"? A video feed from the device camera?

Comment: A live photo is the new feature in the iPhone 6s which records for a couple extra seconds. See: http://www.apple.com/iphone-6s/cameras/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is really no simple out-of-the-box API from Apple to integrate Live Photo in iOS apps.

That being said, there's [an interesting article](http://milen.me/writings/live-photo-ios-api-overview/) that has been going around lately which will explain what Live Photo is under the hood and how you can use it.

Comment: Ya, thanks for your help. I have been getting really confused with integrating live photos in my app. I will give the article a read!

Answer (score 1):

`PHLivePhoto` & `PHLivePhotoView` are available in iOS 9.1+

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHLivePhoto_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/PHLivePhoto

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/PhotosUI/Reference/PHLivePhotoView_Class/

These should be all you need to support Apple's Live Photos in your app.